WordPress with Bedrock on Pantheon. Is it dangerous to set false on DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT and DISALLOW_FILE_MODS consts?
I have a WordPress project with Bedrock on Pantheon. In the application.php file the DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT and DISALLOW_FILE_MODS consts are true by default. In that case, there are no language options for "Site Language". I can select the language if I set false on DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT and DISALLOW_FILE_MODS.
I would like to know, Is it dangerous to set false on DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT and DISALLOW_FILE_MODS consts?
TRUE (By Default)

FALSE


I've found the solution.
To set FALSE on DISALLOW_FILE_EDITS and DISALLOW_FILE_MODS can cause security problems.
I think the best way is to set FALSE to those consts, after that install (check) language and set the TRUE again. I can avoid security problems and work with checked language in that case.
